# Pixel Perfect Collision Detection using Metal

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, metal

I'm trying to adapt cocos2d-x (C++) to do pixel perfect Collision detection, as described in posts like:

https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/pixel-collision-detection-for-v3-x/17680/11

[Pixel Perfect Collision Detection in Cocos2dx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546066/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-in-cocos2dx)

**The problem is :** OpenGL is deprecated in newer versions of iOS, and one must use Metal instead.

I have no experience with Metal, and rather than reinvent the wheel, was wondering if this problem has already been solved.

Comment: you can use PhysicsEditor in Cocos2dx for pixelPerfect collision. https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Comment: @Guru Thanks, but my use case requires me to solve this problem with Metal. I am aware of physics editor, but cannot use it for my problem statement.